# Is it possible to use (compose-capability) with the coin.TRANSFER capability?

Tags: pact-lang

My contract contains a function that transfers funds with `coin.transfer` if some conditions are met. It is guarded by a capability (let's call it `TRANSFER_WRAPPER`). However, when a user calls this function, they must scope their signature to both the `TRANSFER_WRAPPER` and the `coin.TRANSFER` capabilities.

Instead, I would like to use [compose-capability](https://pact-language.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pact-functions.html#compose-capability) within `TRANSFER_WRAPPER` so they only need to scope their signature to the wrapper. For example:

```clj
(module test "sender-keyset"
  (defcap TRANSFER_WRAPPER (receiver:string amount:decimal)
    (compose-capability (coin.TRANSFER "sender" receiver amount))
  )

  (defun transfer-wrapper (receiver:string amount:decimal)
    (with-capability (TRANSFER_WRAPPER receiver amount)
      (coin.transfer "sender" receiver amount)
    )
  )
)
```

However, attempting to use this produces an unexpected error [from the `coin-v4` contract](https://github.com/kadena-io/chainweb-node/blob/master/pact/coin-contract/v4/coin-v4.pact):

```
./root/coin-v4.pact:50:4: Enforce non-upgradeability
 at ./root/coin-v4.pact:50:4: (enforce false "Enforce non-upgradeability")
 at ./root/coin-v4.pact:49:2: (GOVERNANCE)
 at ./test.pact:3:4: (compose-capability (coin.TRANSFER "sender" "receiver" 20.0))
 at ./test.pact:7:21: (TRANSFER_WRAPPER "sender" "receiver" 20.0)
 at ./test.pact:7:4: (with-capability (test.TRANSFER_WRAPPER "sender" "receiver" 20.0) [(coin.transfer "sender" "receiver" 20.0)])
```

You can reproduce the error by placing the Pact snippet above in a file called `test.pact`, and the [`coin-v4`](https://github.com/kadena-io/chainweb-node/blob/master/pact/coin-contract/v4/coin-v4.pact), [`fungible-xchain-v1`](https://github.com/kadena-io/chainweb-node/blob/master/pact/coin-contract/v4/fungible-xchain-v1.pact), and [`fungible-v2`](https://github.com/kadena-io/chainweb-node/blob/8c32fcfff85c4e5b61a9554f0180ca6c90840e42/pact/coin-contract/v2/fungible-v2.pact) contracts into a sibling `root` directory.

Then, paste the contents of this snippet in a `test.repl` file and run it with `pact test.repl`:

```clj
(env-data { "sender-keyset": { "keys": [ "sender-key" ], "pred": "keys-all" } })
(env-sigs [{"key": "sender-key", "caps": []}])
(begin-tx)
; The test depends on the 'coin-v4' contract, which in turn depends on these.
(load "./root/fungible-v2.pact")
(load "./root/fungible-xchain-v1.pact")
(load "./root/coin-v4.pact")
(define-keyset "sender-keyset" (read-keyset "sender-keyset"))
(load "./test.pact")
(commit-tx)

(env-sigs [{"key": "sender-key", "caps": [(test.TRANSFER_WRAPPER "sender" "receiver" 100.0)]}])
(test.transfer-wrapper "sender" "receiver" 20.0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot compose another module's capabilities, and your user must scope `coin.TRANSFER` explicitly, by design.

This ensures that the user's authority over debiting their account can never be delegated away, that the user has explicit and visible control over funds being transferred.

If this were not true, malfeasance could occur. For instance, your wrapper capability could misprepresent how much money was to be transferred, and/or your code could transfer twice, or to a different account, etc.

This is also how Pact avoids the dangerous stateful authorizations seen in EVM contracts. With the `TRANSFER` capability the user is explicitly allowing any code to execute the transfer but only for that transaction, and only for up to the total amount indicated. So it is actually quite helpful for dapps as it avoids bugs from leftover authorizations.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for the explanation. That makes sense -- and is in line with the general concept that capabilities can only be granted within the module where they were defined.